# Display an alert after submitting a form using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS for a login form, and I'm making an API call to the server with username/password and display an alert.

**login.jade**

```
// form
input(type="submit",ng-click="submit()")
div.alert(ng-show="showAlert",class="{{alert}}",ng-animate="{show: 'alert-show', hide: 'alert-hide'}")
button(ng-click="showAlert = !showAlert") fadeIn
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.submit = function () {
  if ($scope.username != undefined && $scope.password != undefined) {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password
      },
      url: 'api/login'
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      if (data.auth) {
        $scope.alert = data.alert;
      } else {
        $scope.alert = data.alert;
      }
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // something else
    });
    $scope.showAlert = true;
  }
}
```

`data.alert` is the class of the alert (`alert-success`, `alert-warning`), but it instantly shows the alert, without fading. If I remove the `$scope.alert = data.alert`, everything works fine. I was thinking about having 2/3 `div.alert`, and having different scopes (`$scope.alert1`, `$scope.alert2`) but I'm sure there is a better way.

Moreover, on the initial load, the `div.alert` is displayed then faded. I could set the alert on `display: none` when loading, but I was looking for a 'cleaner' way.

English is not my native language, so I might have made mistakes, my apologies. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.showAlert = true` is outside of your `success` and `error` callbacks. So you're essentially setting `showAlert` to `true` as soon as you set up your call to `$http`.

Remember that the `$http` service returns a promise and the callbacks (`success` and `error` in this case) are not invoked immediately. They'll only be invoked once the server responds. Try setting `$scope.showAlert = true` inside your success function and see if that is more like what you were expecting.